# Setting value of badge to 0 after opening toggle

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I am working on react chat widget and in this I am able to get the count of new messages I am getting in badge but I want to clear the batch value once I click on the hidden button

```
 export default class App extends React.Component
{
   constructor(props)
   {
      state = {
        count:0
      }
   }
}
```

for incrementing the value

```
this.setState((old_state)=>{
    let new_count = ++old_state.count;
    return { count: new_count }

})
```

inside render function `badge={this.state.count}`

and launcher component looks like this

```
const Launcher = ({ toggle, chatOpened, badge, bgcolor }) =>
  <button type="button" style={{backgroundColor : bgcolor}} className={chatOpened ? 'rcw-launcher rcw-hide-sm' : 'rcw-launcher'} onClick={toggle}>
    {chatOpened ?  
    <img src={close} className="rcw-close-launcher" alt="" />:
     <React.Fragment><Badge badge={badge} /><img src={openLauncher} className="rcw-open-launcher" alt="" /></React.Fragment>
    }
  </button>;
```

I am not able to understand how can I cange the value after reading messages once.

Answer (score 0):

When chatOpened is true, set state count to 0. Or pass 0 to badge count;

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I am looking for a condition in which after reading new messages if I close the chat also then it should not show the badge to me